# Reactivity to Server side object in Meteor

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming

I want to create an object similar to a meteor.collection object having reactive nature. It should work similar to a serverside session so that when ever a data is inserted to that object it should publish automatically to client. Is there any way to create a reactive data source in server? I found that Deps works on the client side and i need the dependency to work on server. Please give me some useful hints

Comment: Does this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/pmnpYRs_NFo point to the right direction?

Comment: actually my problem is i want to publish a user defined objects json data. By default meteors publish can only return cursor. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Would this https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/vhdWPskmLjNDoqjYd help?

Comment: the link shows an invalid location

Comment: No problem with returning a cursor, you can still control what you want to publish even if its only a single doc.  See the 'counts-by-rooms' example just above this section: http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_userId